# AWS CloudFormation - How to obtain VGW Outside IP Addresses for Hardware VPN

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Based on my reading the AWS CloudFormation documentation, the [AWS::EC2::VPNConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpn-connection.html) resource does not offer a return value for the Outside IP addresses for Hardware VPN.

Can I get the Outside IP Addresses within CloudFormation? If the best option is use to a Lambda resource in CloudFormation, pointers to existing code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to get the Outside IP addresses without resorting to a Lambda-backed custom resource so I wrote one. I've included the relevent resource within the template. You can find the full example template in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffbrl/522039e6e1943ef32a4e4dd06a04905d).

```
VPNOutsideIPGenerator:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:get-outside-ip'
  Handler: "index.lambda_handler"
  Timeout: 15
  Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaRole.Arn'
  Runtime: python3.6
  Code:
    ZipFile: |
      import logging
      import boto3
      import cfnresponse

      def lambda_handler(event, context):
          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
          vpn_connection_id = event['ResourceProperties'].get('VPNID', None)
          ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
          response = ec2client.describe_vpn_connections(VpnConnectionIds=[ vpn_connection_id ])
          responseData = {}
          responseData['OutsideIpAddress1'] = response['VpnConnections'][0]['VgwTelemetry'][0]['OutsideIpAddress']
          responseData['OutsideIpAddress2'] = response['VpnConnections'][0]['VgwTelemetry'][1]['OutsideIpAddress']
          logger.info('responseData {}'.format(responseData))
          cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
```